# State of a Initial Component By useState Change to true

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

In my class component wanted change Initial State to True but don't want change to false after true, just change to the true, how can I changed setState? Thanks for help.

```
class Cardlist extends Component {
state = {
    setopen : false
  }
  setOpen = () => this.setState(prevState => ({
    setopen : !prevState.setopen  // I don't know how can changed setState to always true
  }))
render() {
  const { products } = this.props;

return (
  <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.setOpen(true)} className="font-medium">
        Basket
       </button>
       {(this.state.setopen) ? <Card {...products} open={this.state.setopen} /> : ''}
  </div>  
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always keep the state in the setOpen to true.

```
setOpen = () => this.setState(prevState => ({setopen : true})
...
  <div>
       <button onClick={this.setOpen} className="font-medium">
        Basket
       </button>
  </div>
```

---

Make state according to the argument passed

```
  setOpen = (newVal) => this.setState({setopen : newVal})
...
  <div>
       <button onClick={() => this.setOpen(true)} className="font-medium">
        Basket
       </button>
       <button onClick={() => this.setOpen(false)} className="font-medium">
        Basket
       </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: my dude Initial state for first rendering is it true but should be false

Comment: it is false `state = {setopen : false}` . I dont understand properly, like what you require? Can u explain?

Comment: sorry my wrong your answer is properly thank you